# No Preview Tab in Android Studio 2020

Tags: android

[image]

There's no preview tab in my android studio on Tools menu and beside Gradle

Comment: Which version of Android Studio is this? Try using any layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not editing a layout resource. The Preview tool is only visible when you are editing a layout resource (e.g., in `res/layout/` of your `main` source set in your `app` module).

Answer (score 1):

go to view->tool windows-> select preview

[image]